# Delete all posts related to deactivated user with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I delete all posts that are related to a deactivated user? I currently am using this code:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<div class="pad">
    <div class="forum-question">
        <p><%= link_to question.title, question %>
        <br/><span class="pull-right"><%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago, by
         <%= question.user.username %>
<% end %>
```

But the thing is, if a user decides to cancel his account, the loop will fail and cause an undefined error because I am displaying the user's username. To avoid getting it while developing the app, I did this instead:

```
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <div class="pad">
        <div class="forum-question">
            <p><%= link_to question.title, question %>
            <br/><span class="pull-right"><%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago, by
             <% if @user.blank? %>
                deleted user
             <% else %>
             <%= question.user.username %>
             <% end %></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Is there a way to write an if statement that deletes all the user's posts when they press the 'Cancel my account' button?

Answer (score 0):

You could do following method, please do create route. Replace method name with necessary changes if required, **current_user.id** can only be used if you have Devise gem, or substitute with current user's id. I assume you have a **User has many posts** association, if so,

In view file,

```
<%= link_to "Delete my account", delete_posts_path(current_user.id) %>
```

In controller,

```
 def delete_posts
      user_id = params[:id]
      user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
      user.posts.destroy_all
      redirect_to root_path
    end
```

In routes,

```
get 'delete_posts', to: 'controller_name#delete_posts'
```

Insert your controller name in above route.

Comment: Instead of foreach, we may use user.posts.destroy_all

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the `dependent: :destroy` option on the association between your user and the questions they have posted. I'm assuming it's something like:

```
class User
  has_many :questions
```

If you look at the [various options for `dependent` on a `has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) you can set it to:

```
has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
```

Which, from the docs:

> Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed:
>
> `:destroy` causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed

This means that when your user instance is destroyed the questions will also be destroyed.

Whether you actually want to remove all the questions from a user that has cancelled their account or not is a different matter. It would be a shame to remove them if they are of use but that's a different question entirely.